# Custom wxPanel problems

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, panel

I'm writing a C++ wxWidgets application. I want my custom wxButton's that have a EXPANDABLE flag to open up a panel on top of them when I right click. Said panel is also supposed to automatically close when the cursor leaves it, or when the user clicks on one of the buttons it contains.
I created a custom wxPanel class for this job, but I'm having some trouble. The panel is successfully created when I right click on the button, but:

1. The panel is not removed when the cursor leaves it
2. There's an awkward graphical glitch when I move the cursor that cause the other interface elements to get on top of it (?)

Here's my code:

**expandPanel.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "ikeButton.h"

class expandPanel : public wxPanel
{
    wxBoxSizer* sizer;
    int type;

public:
    expandPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY,
                const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
                const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
                long style = wxTAB_TRAVERSAL,
                const wxString & name = wxPanelNameStr);
    ~expandPanel();

    void paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt);
    void paintNow();
    void Render(wxDC& dc);

    void mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

**expandPanel.cpp**

```
#include "expandPanel.h"

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(expandPanel, wxPanel)
    EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW(expandPanel::mouseLeftWindow)
    EVT_PAINT(expandPanel::paintEvent)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

expandPanel::expandPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id,
                        const wxPoint& pos,
                        const wxSize& size,
                        long style,
                        const wxString& name)
{
    wxPanel::Create(parent, id, pos, size, style, name);
    sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    SetSizer(sizer);
}

expandPanel::~expandPanel()
{
}

void expandPanel::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    Render(dc);
}

void expandPanel::paintNow()
{
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    Render(dc);
}

void expandPanel::Render(wxDC& dc)
{
    dc.SetBrush(wxColour(80, 83, 111));
    dc.SetPen(*wxTRANSPARENT_PEN);
    dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, this->GetSize().GetWidth(), this->GetSize().GetHeight());
}

void expandPanel::mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    this->Close();
}
```

(I'm fairly new to this framework)

Ok, I tried switching to wxPopupTransientWindow, but the buttons appear on a different location on screen and sometimes disappear when I move the cursor, but the popup placed in the correct position do not disappear in any way. I feel like I'm doing this completely wrong.

[image: Graphical glitch]

**expandMenu.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/popupwin.h"
#include "ikeButton.h"

class expandMenu : public wxPopupTransientWindow
{
    wxBoxSizer* sizer;

public:
    expandMenu(wxWindow* parent, wxPoint pos, wxSize size, int flags = wxBORDER_NONE);
    ~expandMenu();

    void AddButton(ikeButton* btn);
};
```

**expandMenu.cpp**

```
#include "expandMenu.h"

expandMenu::expandMenu(wxWindow* parent, wxPoint pos, wxSize size, int flags)
    : wxPopupTransientWindow(parent, flags)
{
    this->SetPosition(pos);
    this->SetSize(size);

    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(90, 93, 121));

    sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    sizer->Layout();
    SetSizer(sizer);
}

expandMenu::~expandMenu()
{
}

void expandMenu::AddButton(ikeButton* btn)
{
    unsigned int w = this->GetSize().GetWidth(), h = this->GetSize().GetHeight();
    if (sizer->GetItemCount() > 0)
        this->SetSize(wxSize(w, h + h / sizer->GetItemCount() ));
    sizer->Add(btn, 0, wxEXPAND);
    sizer->Layout();
}
```

Then I generate them like this:

```
void Main::OnExpandableRightClick(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    expandMenu* menu = new expandMenu(this, wxGetMousePosition(), wxSize(50, 50));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) menu->AddButton(new ikeButton(this, wxID_ANY, "TEST " + std::to_string(i), OP));

    menu->Popup();
    evt.Skip();
}
```

(This is a test scenario to see if everything is working)

Comment: check the docs and sample code for wxPopupTransientWindow.

Comment: You can use `Detach` and `Add` for wxSizer and `Layout` again. But as suggested the transient window is maybe a better alternative and saves you from loads of work.

Comment: I tried using wxPopupTransientWindow and I've still got some problems (updated the post)

Comment: "I've still got some problems" ?

Comment: btw, `delete sizer;` you dont need to (should not) do that. https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_sizer.html

Comment: Ok, got rid of that, but the problems still persist.

Comment: "Problems" does not give us any clue at all, you need to explain in detail. Also take a look at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_focus_event.html

Comment: As I said, the information is in the post above. I'm going to add some images if you need them.